# X and Y are not of the same dimesnion. Python Issue

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I am writing a code that uses the forward Euler method to numerically solve some velocity equations. When I run the code, I am getting an error:

```
`   235         y = np.atleast_1d(y)
    236         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 237             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
    238         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    239             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D")
```

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

I have been staring at this for hours, and I can not see how they are not the same dimension. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the full code:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import numpy as n
import pylab as p
steps = 100
m = .15 #Kilograms
D= .07 #Meters
Gamma = .25 #Units of Ns^2/m^4
c = Gamma*D**2
g = 9.8 #Meters per second
v_0 = 25.0 #initial speed
theta_0 = 45.0 #initial angle
dt = .25
t = linspace(0, 100, 10)

Vx = zeros(steps)
Vy = zeros(steps)
x = zeros(steps)
y = zeros(steps)

for i in range(steps - 1):
    Vx[i] = Vx[i-1] - dt*((c/m)*sqrt(Vx[i-1]**2+Vy[i-1]**2)*Vx[i-1])
    Vy[i] = Vy[i-1] - dt*((c/m)*sqrt(Vx[i-1]**2+Vy[i-1]**2)*Vy[i-1] + g)
    x[i] = x[i-1] + dt*(Vx[i-1])
    y[i] = y[i-1] + dt*(Vy[i-1])
    if y[i] < 0.0:
        print (x[i]*y[i-1] - x[i-1]*y[i])/(y[i-1] - y[i])
        break

plot(y, t)
show()
```

Comment: Right after posting, I found the error... my t should have been t=linspace(0,100,steps)

Comment: You sure you want `range(steps - 1)`? It looks like you might want `range(1, steps)`. Otherwise, you'll try to access `Vx[-1]`, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching this. I was so focused on the first error, that I did not see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explaining itself - `y` and `t` should have the same shape but they don't. I suspect this is what you want:

```
t = linspace(0, 100, steps)
```

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib gives error if the dimensions of your arrays are not matched. You can simply check it and squeeze it to desired dimensions using numpy

```
>>> x = np.array([[[0], [1], [2]]])
```

> > > x.shape

(1, 3, 1)

> > > np.squeeze(x, axis=(2,)).shape

(1, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays do not have the same dimension, that's correct by matplotlib. You can check the dimensions and sizes (the «shape») by doing the following:

```
>>> y.shape
(100,)
>>> t.shape
(10,)
```

So just do

```
t = linspace(0, 100, steps)
```